# best way to achieve 30,000 inserts per second into SQL

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

Without using SSIS or Bulk Inserts, Bulk Load, or Bulk anything; I need to be able to just call a stored procedure that inserts data.

I have a 2.8 gig file that contains over 18 million records.
My solution, written in C# and taking advantage of Parallel processing and ASYNC-AWAIT, uses multithreaded processes on multiple servers to parse this file in 10 minutes. However, no matter what I try, additional threads, additional servers, even inserting multiple records in one call by passing a table valued parameter, the fastest I can insert these records into an SQL database is 3100 per second. The stored procedure contains only the INSERT statement, and the table has no indexes or keys. At this rate it takes 100 minutes to store the parsed results  into a database. I have a need to bring this down to 10 minutes, meaning I have to increase my ability to insert records ten-fold. The database is my only bottleneck.

A) Will using multiple filegroups do the trick?

B) What about breaking out the table into versions, such as:
EtlRecords001, EtlRecords002, EtlRecords003, ..., EtlRecords100.
The idea here being to make the tables smaller.

C) Lastly, spreading the work by using multiple SQL servers
The idea here also being to use smaller tables AND combined with using several database servers.

In the case of B and C, the solution would obviously have processes on different machines target different; B.) table versions; C) server instances.

Not knowing much about filegroups, I have to believe there's a better way than cases B and C.

And lastly, buying a 48 core server with 128 gig of ram isn't a viable option for me :)

Comment: While you are uploading, is CPU, hard disk or memory peak?

Comment: Rawitas, I do not have remote logon access to the database server, so I could not answer this. In any case, this server has over 30 other databases and I do not know how other applications in the enterprise use these databases. Hogging resources is really not an option, so I need to be able to solve this without spiking the cpu, hard disk, or memory. However, adding tables, filegroups, and even creating new databases on the other servers is something I have permissions for.

Comment: Using Activity Monitor, I can see there are a lot of waiting tasks; I see spikes above 60.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to divide the data into batches? Since you are unable to measure the computational resources bottleneck. My best guess is your memory is the bottleneck.

```
create cursor ....
select YEAR(timestamp)-- or anything else

while ....
    insert into table1(...)
    select * from whatever 
    where YEAR(timestamp) = year
end
```

Second point `exec dbo.insert1 with recompile` You might wanna recompile the sp to get new plan which is suitable for data size each time you call it.

Comment: I am actually already dividing data into batches, this is how I'm able to parse a 2.8 gig file in 10 minutes. In other words, when I comment out my datalayer code, my trace log on the various machines show 18 million records successfully parsed, and the entire process completes in 10 minutes. When I uncomment my datalayer calls, trace code reveals the bottleneck. All 18 million records are inserted into the database successfully, but this time the process took an hour and forty two minutes.

Comment: Are you able to get query plan somehow? Can you try run sp with recompile?

Comment: It's a simple insert statement into a table with 7 columns. There are no views, no primary keys, no constraints, no indexes, no defaults, and I use no hints, no ctes, and no logic statements, just 1 basic insert statement.

Comment: Execution plan is related to resource allocation so sometimes running sp with recompile helps.

Comment: Been reading on using with recompile; I will try this and report back what performance boost I get if any. Thanks!

Comment: Adding "with compile" did not help.

Comment: sorry to hear man. I wish I could test with you so that I can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use table variables.  You can pass a table variable loaded to stored procedure, and from there, you can INSERT / UPDATE / MERGE, whatever you want to do.

Doing that, I was able to get from a Silverlight Service all the way down to SQL Server via a web service and 50,000 records a second was easily achievable, and this was circa 2010s before the advent of SSD.